# MySQL ERD checking

Tags: mysql, erd

I am confused that is Reservation table a composite table? If yes, should I create composite key for that table or remain as that? If remain as that, will that cause any problem in the future?

[image]

Comment: This question tends more in the direction of primarily opinion-based because we don't know anny facts (valid user cases) how the system will be used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the single-column PK is good.

Alternatively you could have the PK (CID, AdID, RmID). But then... what would happen if the same customer rented the same room next month? Then this PK would not allow it.

Comment: "Then this PK would not allow it." Assuming the same Admin (AdID) will approve it.. Besides a status (approved or not) which AdID more or less is i think it's a bad candidate for in a PK but that's mine opinion.. 
"I think the single-column PK is good." yes i also agree on this.